# Defining Admins Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How can I define a method between Users and Admins? I am using Omniauth Twitter for my users but there are actions that I want to make sure users can not do if they are not admins. I have bundled the gem Active admin but because I am not using devise, any user can currently access the Admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I'd create a `role` attribute on your User model, and have it default to say "customer" or whatever a default user is, but have the ability to set some user's role to "admin". You should be able to set that using Active Admin's edit page. Than create a custom method on your User model, or maybe create a helper method, whatever you prefer...something like:

```
def admin?
  if self.role == "admin"
    true
  else
   false
end
```

That way you wrap sensitive info (like info on your dashboard) in a `user.admin?` if statement.

```
if user.admin?
  ..display stuff..
end
```

Or check out this: http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html